# How can I capitalize every third letter of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, capitalize

How can I capitalize every third letter of a string in C#?

I loop through the whole string with a *for* loop, but I can't think of the sequence right now.

Comment: Could you please show your string and tell us what do you want as a result?

Comment: how about using a counter, make it count to 2, when it hits 2, capitalize the letter and reset the counter to 0 ?

Comment: use counter and mod 3

Comment: Is this starting with the first char or is it the third (i.e. is this chars 1,4,7,... or is this 3,6,9,...)?

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you just want something like this:

```
// String is immutable; copy to a char[] so we can modify that in-place
char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i += 3)
{
    chars[i] = char.ToUpper(chars[i]);
}
// Now construct a new String from the modified character array
string output = new string(chars);
```

That assumes you want to start capitalizing from the first letter, so "abcdefghij" would become "AbcDefGhiJ". If you want to start capitalizing elsewhere, just change the initial value of `i`.

Comment: this will probably through an exception while trying to cast upper to a special character.

Comment: @AftabAhmed No it won't.

Comment: @AftabAhmed: No it won't. `char.ToUpper('1')` is just `'1'` for example. Look at the documentation for `char.ToUpper` - does that say anything about throwing exceptions?

Comment: @JonSkeet +1 for not immediately jumping on the "bad question" bandwagon, refreshing for sure...

Comment: @jdphenix: Well it's not a *great* question, that's for sure - no sample input/output, no code showing what's already been tried, and no interaction since asking the question :(

Answer (score 6):

```
        var s = "Lorem ipsum";
        var foo = new string(s
            .Select((c, i) => (i + 1) % 3 == 0 ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c)
            .ToArray());
```

Comment: While that will work, using LINQ for this feels like overkill to me.

Comment: Fair enough - each to their own :)

Answer (score 1):

You are already looping through the characters inside a string? Then add a counter, increment it on each iteration, and if it is 3, then use `.ToUpper(currentCharacter)` to make it upper case. Then reset your counter.

Comment: Why would you increment it by 1 and then check whether it's 3? You already need to know the index of the characters, so just increment that by 3 on each iteration.

Comment: I interpreted that to mean "I've tried doing this by looping through the whole string, but then I got stuck." Even if that's not the case, you can just keep incrementing the counter and check `whether counter % 3` is 0 - there's no need to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regular expression.

If the answer is every third char then you want

```
var input = "sdkgjslgjsklvaswlet";
var regex = new Regex("(..)(.)");
var replacement = regex.Replace(input, delegate(Match m)
                     {
                         return m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper();
                     });
```

If you want every third character, but starting with the first you want:

```
var input = "sdkgjslgjsklvaswlet";
var regex = new Regex("(.)(..)");
var replacement = regex.Replace(input, delegate(Match m)
                     {
                         return m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() + m.Groups[2].Value;
                     });
```

If you want a loop, you can convert to a character array first, so you can alter the values.

For every third character:

```
var x = input.ToCharArray();
for (var i = 2; i <x.Length; i+=3) {
    x[i] = char.ToUpper(x[i]);
}
var replacement = new string(x);
```

For every third character from the beginning:

```
var x = input.ToCharArray();
for (var i = 0; i <x.Length; i+=3) {
    x[i] = char.ToUpper(x[i]);
}
var replacement = new string(x);
```