# How to make only chosen characters uppercase in C#

Tags: c#

I want to make every other letter uppercase, how do I do that?

Code:

```cs
String a = ("aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö");

for (int i=0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(a.ToUpper()[i]+ ",");
}
```

Comment: What do you have a problem with? Selecting "every other letter"?

Comment: Hint: "If `i` is divisible by 2", then it's even, and that could be used to designate "every other letter".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize every third letter ot a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165453/how-to-capitalize-every-third-letter-ot-a-string-in-c)

Comment: I want to make for example aBcDeFg etc.

Comment: Take the code in the duplicate's answers, change the 3 to a 2, try it. Doesn't work? Try changing the initial value of `i`.

Comment: You haven't defined what the result should be.  Please update your question with your functional requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq:

```
string a = "aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö";

var converted = 
    new string(a.Select((ch, i) => ((i % 2) == 0) ? ch : Char.ToUpper(ch)).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(converted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment your loop by 2. 
Example:

```
String a = ("aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö");
for (int i=0; i<a.Length; i+=2)
   Console.Write(a.ToUpper()[i]+ ",");
```

For every even alphabet start loop from 0 and for odd start from 1.

Answer (score 1):

Linq answer is very good and has the advantage to be one liner, but a normal loop here is twice faster than the Linq solution

```
char[] a = "aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö".ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        a[i] = Char.ToUpper(a[i]);
    }
}
string result = new string(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = ("aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö");
for (int i=0; i<a.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
         a = a.Substring(0, i) + a.Substring(i, 1).ToUpper() + a.Substring(i);
    }
}
```

The % symbol is modulo, in this context if the index if divisible by 2 make the symbol upper case.

EDIT: as correctly pointed out, string are immutable, I've edited appropriately. This most likely isn't the most efficient way of doing this, I'd recommend using LINQ for a more efficient algorithm

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: Well.. don't do that with the substrings. You're going to create so many throw-away intermediaries. You've also got an issue with i starting at 0, and i-1 being less than 0 for your Substring call's length parameter.

Comment: Also what is `n`?

Comment: n etc is what happens when you answer a question in about 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Linq**.

```
string oldString = "aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö";
    string alternatedString = string.Concat(
        oldString.ToLower().Select((character, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? character : char.ToUpper(character)));
```

Output: aÁbDeÉðFgHiÍjKlMnOóPrStUúVxYýÞæÖ

Or

```
string oldString = "aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö";
        StringBuilder alternatedString = new StringBuilder();
        for(int index=0; index<oldString.Length; index++)
        {
            if(index % 2 == 0)
                alternatedString.Append(oldString[index].ToString().ToLower());
            else
                alternatedString.Append(oldString[index].ToString().ToUpper());
        }
```

Output: aÁbDeÉðFgHiÍjKlMnOóPrStUúVxYýÞæÖ

Comment: yeah, that is true. Updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to go through each `char` in the `string`. If it is divisible by 2 then that means its every other letter. So make that upper case, if not divisible by 2 then leave it as it is. Rejoin all the `char`s together in an array then convert that back into a string.

```
String a = ("aábdeéðfghiíjklmnoóprstuúvxyýþæö");  

var convertedString = new string(a
  .Select((c, i) => (i + 1) % 2 == 0 ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c)
  .ToArray());
```